# Mouse doesn't display correctly with Xinerama in Gnome

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, ubuntu-10.04, gnome, xorg

When I move my mouse to the second screen, for a moment the cursor can be seen on it, then it appears to return to the original screen. Then when I move the mouse around, the pointer is showing on the original screen, but if I click something, the pointer acts as if is on the new screen.

The mouse pointer only correctly displays itself once I click the left mouse button after moving it to the new screen.

This problem only appears when I use Gnome but not when I use KDE.